# Existence of minimal subset of dual ball such that the intersection of kernels is trivial

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let $(V, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ be a separable Banach space and let $B_{V^*}$ denote the closed ball in the dual $V^*$. Suppose we have a family $C \subseteq B_{V^*}$ such that $\bigcap_{\Lambda \in C} \mathrm{ker}(\Lambda) = \{ 0 \}$. Is it always possible to find a subfamily $\widetilde{C} \subseteq C$ such that $\bigcap_{\Lambda \in \widetilde{C}} \mathrm{ker}(\Lambda) = \{ 0 \}$, but removing any element of $\widetilde{C}$ makes this equality false?

Comment: Isn't this wrong for the euclidean unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Right, it is definitely wrong... I need to rework the whole question...

Comment: (The above comments were about the previous version of a question)

Comment: If I understand correctly, If we were to take such functionals, then the intersections of their kernels would consist only of $\{ 0 \}$ and removing any of these functionals wouldn't change that fact?

However, would it be the same regardless of whether we have chosen Hamel or Schauder ONB?

Comment: Wouldn't we have a situation that every functional has a value of 1 only on one element of such a basis and 0 on the others, so, after removing it, the intersection of kernels of the other functionals would leave us with a 1-d subspace induced by the element of basis on which the removed functional had a value of 1?

Comment: @KacperKurowski: You are right. I misread your question.

Comment: It is false, though. We can take $V=C[0,1]$ and $\Lambda$ as the collection of the Dirac measures $\delta_x$, $0\le x\le 1$. Then a subcollection will have zero intersection of the kernels if and only if the corresponding points form a dense set, but then you can of course always remove one more point.

Comment: Thank you, that's a neat counterexample. On a somewhat unrelated note, is the closed convex hull (in the weak-$*$ topology) of this collection equal to the closed ball in the dual $V^*$?

Comment: @KacperKurowski: It's not quite the unit ball since such measures (are positive and) have total mass one, but you can indeed approximate any such measure $\mu$ by convex combinations $\sum c_j \delta_{j/n}$, say, with $c_j=\mu([(j-1)/n, j/n))$.